# Mysql - Select position of value in one column grouped by another column values

Tags: mysql

I have table with 2 column and I want to write a query to fetch the row position of given value in the group of another column data set:

[image]

For example I want to get the position of contestant "anku_883" in group name "punee" and "ansh" that is I am expecting for "punee" position 5 and for "ansh" position 1 using single query.

I have written the following query in which if I specify one particular group name (eg ansh) then I can get the position of contestant in that group correctly:

```
SELECT x.group_name
, x.position 
FROM (SELECT t.group_name
     , @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
     FROM game t 
     JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
     WHERE t.group_name='ansh' 
     ORDER BY t.add_time
) x 
WHERE x.contestant = 'anku_883'
```

I want to extend this query such that I get the position of a particular contestant in all the group name in which its name appears. Something like:

```
SELECT x.group_name
, x.position 
FROM (SELECT t.group_name
     , @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
     FROM game t 
     JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
     WHERE t.group_name in ('punee','ansh') 
     ORDER BY t.add_time
) x 
WHERE x.contestant = 'anku_883'
```

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets, so there is no inherent ordering without a field that specifies the ordering.  Do you have such a field?

Comment: Yes, I have another column in that table (add_time) that I use in Order By. Please see my edited query.